# Problems intalling dict_en.oxt

Tags: java, openoffice.org, uno

I am new to OpenOffice, so, as my Italian friend here say... takaht eeeasy.
In trying to install dict-en, I get an error that reads:
..\AppData\Roaming\OpenOffice\4\user\uno_package\cache\uno_packages\sv1mgoq1.tmp_\dict_en.oxt does not exist

OO works all hanky dory, with the only exception that I don't have a English Canadian (en-ca) Dictionary/Spell checker. This really sucks, dude, I don't only have to focus on my work, but also on my terrible spelling habits.
What is UNO any ways? And no, I am not talking about uno, dos, tres kid of thing, but the "OpenOffice UNO". 
Thanks kids and keep your eyes on the puck!

Answer (score 0):

What version and brand of OOo you are using?
On which operating system?

Where did you download the OXT from?

How you tried to install the extension (command line, double click in a file manager, from within OOo)?

Comment: Dude! thanks for the help. I have OpenOffice 4.1.1 running on Win7. I don't sweat the problems dude, I like taking the easiest way possible, so I downloaded the OXT file from the OpenOfice website and then I just clicked install, what else do I do?

Comment: For Canadian English, I would go to Extension Website and d/l http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/project/en_CA

Then install it via Extension Manager. 

If the error still persists you want try resetting your OO user profile.